# How to get SOAP message while using a Axis 1.4 wsdl2java-generated client

Tags: java, axis, web-services, webservice-client

This is probably an easy question for anyone with any moderate expertise with web services using Apache Axis.

I have a web service client that was generated by wsdl2java in Axis 1.4. I am writing unit tests that need to access the actual SOAP message itself, and do a comparison to the client side java classes which are generated by Axis. (don't ask)

How can I retrieve the actual SOAP message from a response from the service?

From what I can gather from searching around is that I have to get the MessageContext.
I have tried something along these lines...

MessageContext mc = MessageContext.getCurrentContext(); 
String message = mc.getCurrentMessage().getSOAPPartAsString();

But mc is null in this case....

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how it's done.

http://users.skynet.be/pascalbotte/rcx-ws-doc/jaxrpchandler.htm

Comment: Could you please expand the answer? In addition to possible link rot in the future (yay, 6 years!), the page at the link has a lot of code and it's not immediately apparent "how it's done". So a quick summary here with the relevant code snippet only (not an entire wall of code) will be very helpful!

Comment: The link is broken, can you update the answer?

Answer (score 3):

When `_call` object is filled calling the line below gives it.

`String request=_call.getMessageContext().getRequestMessage()
               .getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().toString();`

For response use the below one

`_call.getMessageContext().getResponseMessage()
                    .getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().toString()`

`Call` is a `org.apache.axis.client.Call` as you know.